# how can I access a ec2-xx-xx-xx-xx.us-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com ? this link won't open in my browser:

Tags: url

how can I access a us-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com ? this link won't open in my browser:

This page isn’t working didn’t send any data. ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE

i'm not familiar with it, it starts with EC2

Answer (score 3):

This answer could have been answered by a Google search.

[EC2](https://www.google.com.au/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&ved=0ahUKEwjMsIqj-7DZAhWCfrwKHdWhAWsQFggnMAA&url=https%3A%2F%2Fdocs.aws.amazon.com%2FAWSEC2%2Flatest%2FUserGuide%2Fconcepts.html&usg=AOvVaw0vtjc0aaPJCPDTZztn_BGH) is a service provided by AWS that provides remote, virtual compute resources.

When an EC2 instance is provisioned, it is assigned a unique address.

The components of the address are as follows:

`unique ec2 instance identifier . aws availability region . resource type .`

Usually, EC2 instances are not publicly accessible. AWS [recommends](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/UsingIAM.html#intro-to-security-groups) and enforces a configuration like:

`NAT Gateway (Internet Gateway) -> VPC (Private Cloud) -> ELB (Load Balancer) -> EC2 instance`

So given the recommended access controls, and the fact that this is a compute resource which may be expecting some kind of authorisation, payload, or not even be running a web-service, it is normal that you are not able to resolve this address in your browser.

You have tagged "penetration-test" in your question, however it appears you may not have the right knowledge, project scope, or permissions to be conducting a pen-test in this environment.

I suggest speaking with someone who has more experience in this space before going further.

Answer (score 0):

If the underlying infrastructure is correctly configured as @llorrac mentioned (IGW -> VPC -> Host), then the reason you cannot access the instance is probably because of the Security Group configuration attached to that instance. Either your ip is not whitelisted in the SG or the SG is not open on the ports you are trying to connect to it on (80, 443 etc.).

IGW = Internet Gateway (needed for in/out communications for a public subnet in AWS)

VPC = Virtual Private Cloud (Logical group of network assets in AWS)

SG = Security Group (Akin to a stateful software defined firewall within the VPC)